# Is it possible to replicate tables from multiple databases in Google Cloud?

Tags: microservices, database-replication, event-sourcing

The company that I work at uses [a microservices architecture](https://microservices.io/index.html) with [the 'database per service' pattern](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/database-per-service.html). This pattern makes it harder to query based on data from multiple services, since each service has its own database. Imagine a service for managing your products and one for managing stock. You would have to somehow combine the data from both services to query for products based on stock.

I know that [event sourcing](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html) and [API composition](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/api-composition.html) are potential solutions to the problem, but I was wondering if it is possible to continuously replicate specific tables from the product and stock databases based on database transaction logs. Wouldn't this be much simpler than say implementing an event based solution like event sourcing? One service that I am working with contains a lot of domain events, which would make implementing and maintaining event-based solution rather complex.

Another reason for why I am considering to look at the problem from a different angle is that there is a lot of data. In-memory joins with say API composition will most likely be slow.

To sum it all up, I would like to know if it is possible to continuously replicate specific tables from different databases into one database.

The technologies that my company uses are primarily Spring Framework and PostgreSQL.

Comment: I am considering to build a test setup with 'logical replication' (see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication.html). It is a PostgreSQL feature that allows the user to replicate specific tables across instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would step back and ask why you have microservices (including why you have multiple databases).  This is because it's quite easy to make choices that are superficially easy but which achieve that ease by negating the reason you had the microservices to begin with, and in such a situation, it may in fact be easier to just not do microservices.

For example, you might be doing microservices because you want to be able to have the team maintaining your product service be able to make changes without coordinating with the stock service or vice versa.  By setting up a direct replication of a table from service A's database into service B's database, you essentially require many changes service A might want to make to that table to be coordinated with service B.  It's perhaps less operationally coupled than unifying the services into a monolith, but in terms of developer velocity, you're giving up a fair amount.

Alternatively, if the rationale is to allow one service to be down (failures, maintenance, releases: doesn't matter) without taking the others down, a replication which guarantees strong consistency implies that taking service B's database down prevents service A from updating its database (because if you allowed service A to update its database in that situation, you couldn't have strong consistency).

Rather than direct replication, it might make sense to use change data capture (e.g. with Debezium) to publish a stream of changes from the transaction logs (e.g. to Kafka).  The critical difference from logical replication is that the consumer can, for instance, choose to ignore updates to columns it doesn't care about: the stock service might include details like where things are stocked in a warehouse, for instance, which is data you don't need for answering a query like "show me the products in this category which are in stock".  This can be a nice middle ground between going full event-sourcing and other approaches.

Comment: The usage of a microservices architecture is not something that I can change. I am strongly considering to use Apache Debezium. One of the requirements of my assignment is that development should not take too much work and change data capture might just be an elegant solution.